# C: Struct pointer-array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm trying to create and initialise a pointer to an array of pointers to structs. This array will be passed around to many parts of my program.

This is my code:

**file.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

typedef struct Object Object;

void init(Object*** objs);

#endif
```

**file.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "file.h"

struct Object
{
    int a, b;
};

void init(Object*** objs)
{
    *objs = malloc(5 * sizeof(Object*));

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        *objs[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Object));
        *objs[i] -> a = i;     // arbitrary member access
        *objs[i] -> b = i * 2; // arbitrary member access
    }

}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "file.c"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Object** prog_objs;

    init(&prog_objs);
    // should now have a pointer to an array to pass around

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("Obj: %d, %d\n", prog_objs[i] -> a, prog_objs[i] -> b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why this ins't working. I'm positive my `main()` is correct and the issue is somewhere in the `init()` function. I've tried a variety of different ways to initialise the array elements to be struct pointers, but I keep getting compile errors or segfaults.

Any advice on where my issues are is much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*objs[i]` is a precedence error. It parses as `*(objs[i])`.

It should be `(*objs)[i]` instead.

Comment: This has fixed it! Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

*`*objs[i]` does not mean what you think it means*, it means:

```
*(objs[i])
```

Dereferencing the element at *position **i***... But what you need is:

```
(*obj)[i]
```

Which means dereferencing `obj`, then accessing the dereferenced member...

As to why this happens, this is due to the `[]` operator having higher precedence than `*` operator... So the `[]` operator evaluates first and then the `*` operator does...

**Another way you can solve your problem is by:**

```
obj[0][i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered by @melpomene as the problem is occurring due to the [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Since the `init()` function is doing allocation as well as initialization work, to avoid such kind of problems, you can modify the `init()` to return `Object**` type instead of taking `Object*** objs` as parameter. You can do:

```
Object** init(void)
{
    Object** objs;
    objs = malloc(5 * sizeof(Object*));
    if (objs == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //You can  return NULL from here and handle it in calling function
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        objs[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct Object));
        if (objs[i] == NULL) {
           fprintf (stderr, "Failed to allocate memory");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        objs[i] -> a = i;     // arbitrary member access
        objs[i] -> b = i * 2; // arbitrary member access
    }
    return objs;
}
```

In the calling function, you can do:

```
Object** prog_objs = init();
```

Also, follow good programming practice. Always check `malloc` return and ensure to `free` the allocated memory once you are done with it.